# How to catch Sinatra::NotFound?

Tags: exception, sinatra

http://rollbar.com is error tracker service.
**UPDATE**

I found this URL on dashboard - http://52.38.72.163/robots.txt. It seems I need to change nginx config

Robots come to my production site and are causing Sinatra::NotFound.

I tried to fix it like this:

application.rb

```
 class Application < Sinatra::Base
   def route_missing
     if @app
       forward
     else
       halt 404, 'Not found'
     end
   end        
   # also tried this
   error Sinatra::NotFound do
     'Route not found'
   end
 end
```

I still receive mails about this error.

Anyone faced this problem ? Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try the following ?

```
class App < Sinatra::Base

    set :raise_errors, false
    set :show_exceptions, false

    error do
        redirect to('/') # or something else
    end
```

Comment: I will try. I suppose there is a problem with domain configuration

Answer (score 0):

I blocked access by IP on nginx level

nginx/sites-enabled/...conf

```
server {
  // other configurations
  if ($host = "52.38.72.163") {
      return 404;
  }
}
```